# tools for defining and running complex applications with docker

Tags: docker, fig

When you use docker on your develop life-cicle is common that you need some tools for defining and running complex applications. Actually exist somes alternatives like: **fig**, **crane** and the newest **docker-compose**.

I have experience with fig and crane, but recently I found some references of docker-compose but I don't know why docker group reinvent the wheel in this area.

What it's the better option to run on your local machine a complex environment with docker, for example to do: exploratory test, unit test, or to wake up a group of data services like: postgres, redis, mongodb.

Comment: docker-compose is the new name for fig.

Comment: thanks @adrian-mouat, but do you know if docker-composer has a way to restrict resources like crane? for example cpu or ram?

Comment: Yes, you can set `mem_limit` and `cpu_shares` (http://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#working95dir-entrypoint-user-hostname-domainname-mem95limit-privileged-restart-stdin95open-tty-cpu95shares)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, the Docker team [has announced](http://blog.docker.com/2015/02/orchestrating-docker-with-machine-swarm-and-compose/) that it will be releasing new tools for managing your containers, including [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose).

Compose has already [replaced Fig](https://github.com/docker/fig) and the activity on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Aenhancement) suggests that it might potentially introduce new features down the road as other tools are released.

I am a long-time Fig user, so I'm a bit biased when I suggest that you now continue with using `docker-compose`. If your going to give Crane a chance, then you also might be interested to explore using GNU Make for managing your containers.